# Xcode 8 cannot run on device, provisioning profile problems mentioning Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, xcode8, fastlane-match

I am running OS X El Capitan and using the Xcode 8 GM seed (8A218a) and I am trying to run my app on my iPhone 6 with iOS 10 GM seed, 10.01 (14A403), which is paired to my Apple Watch running watchOS 3 GM seed (14S326).

I am using Match for handling provisioning profiles and certificates, it has been working beautifully so far.

I recently changed the bundle identifier, so created a new App Id in member center and reconfigured match etc. I have the development certificate and provisioning profile installed on my Mac. I have deleted the old certificates and the old provisioning profiles.

Everything is just working fine running on the simulator. But when I try to run it on my iPhone Xcode 8 is displaying on error:

> Provisioning profile "match Development com.XXX.YYY" doesn't include the currently selected device "ZZZ's Apple Watch".

It shows another error as well:

> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

This is under *Target -> General*:
[image]

*Target -> Build Settings* looks like this:
[image: target_build_settings]

I don't have an Apple Watch extension for this app. So why is Xcode 8 giving me errors relating to my Apple Watch?

Also what does the second error mean? *Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'*?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same issue today - XCode Version 8.0 (8A218a) - and fixed it with two simple steps (instead of the more complicated approach above:

- add the Apple Watch to member center (did not find a copy&paste option either)
- edit the development provisioning profile and add the watch to devices, save
- go to XCode prefs, move the old provisioning profile to trash (right click on the name) and download the new version
- set the new provisioning profile in project editor

No restart, clean or anything else needed. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This is the better answer. You do not need to blow away all your profiles and certificates.

Comment: Great, just add apple watch device and renew dev profile.

Comment: How did you add the device to the member centre? The little `+` icon is greyed-out for me in my version of https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/

Comment: Note that the iOS Provisioning Portal will indicate a valid UDID if it's the right length but contains incorrect characters. But if Xcode shows the updated provisioning portal as Ineligible when you try to select it in the project settings, that could mean you have a typo somewhere in your UDID.

Comment: Awesome Answer...Thanks

Comment: I added the device on developer.apple.com. Then, I just needed to navigate to the signing and capabilities tab of my project in Xcode and the provisioning profile automatically updated. However, it wouldn't update automatically before I actually navigated there (even after attempting to clean, rebuild, and archive).

Answer (score 65):

This did work for me:

- Disable bluetooth on the iPhone
- Disconnect & reconnect iPhone
- Build and Run
- Enable bluetooth again when you are finished with the debugging session

Comment: This is my preferred answer because I don't want to add my watch to clients' device lists. I find it pretty annoying that, even though the app isn't targeting Apple Watch, one hits this error at all. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! What ungodly mess have Apple created for this to be the required solution... an app that's not going to run on Apple Watch doesn't need to require the watch to be in the profile and turning off the bluetooth shouldn't make it forget the watch was ever there :'(

Comment: Apple at its best, as usual. And we still have to pay them.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. If adding the watch to the profile is a massive process (if you work in large org) then this is a great common sense and working answer

Comment: Now it's a little bit different (easier) : you have to put your Apple Watch in Airplane mode

Answer (score 7):

After putting my Apple Watch on Power Reserve (or turning it off, or Airplane mode, or...) and waiting a bit for Xcode to realize it was gone, I was able to run the app on my phone again.

Airplane mode is easiest.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with Version 8.0 (8A218a). It seems to go away when I:

1. Reselect the certificate (via UI)
2. Clean all (ctrl+cmd+shift+k)
3. Restart Xcode
4. Run the projet (which is possible after 1-3)

If I change the code, I get the same error again. Do not be fooled by Xcode actually indicating that everything is ok in the UI - but still gives the error. Its 1-4 again.

Regarding the 2. error. Looking at your screenshot I see no matching "Signing certificate" - which the message indicates is required. The above 1-4 also removed that error for me.

I really do hope there is a better solution to this issue and that we are missing something obvious! The restart-run cycle is not that efficient ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this did not work for me however.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same errors, what happened was iTunes/Apple updated the provisioning profile and I had to accept the new update. Once I logged into "developer.apple.com" I just had to accept the new update and then go back to Xcode, close the project, reopen, and then download the provisioning profile to my new iPhone and then run the project. This is what worked for me.

I didn't have to delete anything or what the other answers are suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 8:

select the target -> General -> Signing -> select Automatically manage signing

then Xcode will help you to fix this.

Comment: I said that I am using Match for PP management, so no I don't want automatic management of PPs ;)